# A proof on the existence of an injective function

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In *La matematica della verità* (p.65-66, theorem **3.5.3**), Ettore Casari proves the following theorem:

> $f : A \to B$ is injective iff  for all $g : C \to A, h : C \to A$ and all $C$:
> $$f \circ g \equiv f \circ h \to g \equiv h$$

His proof for the right-to-left hand is unclear to me. He writes:

> Consider the set C and the functions $g$ and $h$ defined as follows: C: = { z } (where $z$ is some individual), $g,h : C \to A$, $g(z) := x$ and $h(z) := y$. It follows that $f(g(z)) = f(h(z))$, i.e that $(f \circ g)\,z = (f \circ h)\,z$, and since $z$ is the only argument of $f \circ g$ and $f \circ h$, $f \circ g \equiv f \circ h$ and therefore, by hypothesis, $g \equiv h$, so that $g(z) = h(z)$ and $x = y$.

I don't understand how he argues on the basis of a very specific set $C$ and a very specific stipulation (that $g(z) := x$ and $h(z) := y$) to the claim that for **any** $C$, and any functions $g,h : C \to A$, it follows that $f$ is injective.

How does this proof generalise to other cases where $C$ is not the set as defined above, and $g$ and $h$ are not as defined)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have three statments here, $P_1$, $P_2$ and $Q$ which are given by

$P_1$:= for all sets $C$ and for all $g,h:C \rightarrow A$ we have $f \circ g \equiv f \circ h \implies g \equiv h$
$P_2$:= for the set $C = \{z\}$ and for all $g,h:C \rightarrow A$ we have $f \circ g \equiv f \circ h \implies g \equiv h$
$Q$:= $f : A \rightarrow B$ is injective.

In his proof he basically proves $P_2 \implies Q$.
It is also immediate that $P_1 \implies P_2$ (check this!, this is what you are asking).
So by transitivity we have $P_1 \implies Q$, which is what we wanted.

Finally a remark about how to interpret this theorem:
As you probably know we have that a funciton is *invertible iff it is bijective*. Note here that invertible means **left and right invertible** (which is almost never mentioned) and it follows without assumption that the left and the right inverse are equal if they exist.
This theorem just tells us that a function is *left invertible iff it is injective*. Indeed suppose $f$ is left invertible with function $\tilde{f}$ then we can say that $f \circ g \equiv f \circ h \implies \tilde{f} \circ f \circ g \equiv \tilde{f} \circ f \circ h \implies g \equiv h$, so we can see that the statment $Q$ above implies that $f$ is left-invertible (and the converse is also true).
Similarly he will likely prove that *right invertible iff it is surjective*.
So, what I wnat to say is that the right hand side $Q$ seems kind of hard to interpret at first. But the idea is just that $Q$ is equivalent to $f$ being left-invertible, whis is much more intuitive in my opinion. In general, these kinds of theorems give characterisations between kinds of invertibility and properties of functions like injectiveness.

Comment: Try to convince yourself that we are trying to prove $P_1 \implies Q$, so it is sufficient to prove $P_1 \implies P_2 \implies Q$. So we do not need $P_2$ implies $P_1$, we need $P_1$ implies $P_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The hypothesis is that we are given that for any $C$ we have some condition, then prove $f$ is injective. We don't need to prove that for every $C$ with some condition, then $f$ is injective. This is why considering a singleton set is sufficient.

Since $g,h$ are functions from $C$ to $A$, we have that $g(z):=x$ and $h(z):=y$ for some elements $x,y \in A$. $f(g(z)) = f(h(z))$  comes from the fact that when proving the injectivity of some function $f$, one can assume $f(x) = f(y)$. Then as $z$ is the only argument , we must have $f \circ g \equiv f \circ h$ so that $ g \equiv h$ by hypothesis.

Thus, $g(z) = h(z)$ which means $x=y$.